# pg-cloudflare won't allow my serverless to deploy

Tags: aws-serverless

I've been trying hard to deploy my serverless, since I added a serverless service using a PostgreSQL driver/or a redshift library (both are triggering the same issue).

Here is my error :

```
   ERROR in /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/pg-cloudflare/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cloudflare:sockets' in '/Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/pg-cloudflare/dist'
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/pg-cloudflare/dist/index.js 35:38-66
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/pg/lib/stream.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/lib/redshift.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/services/apiService/handler.js

ERROR in /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/node-redshift/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-native' in '/Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/node-redshift/node_modules/pg/lib/native'
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/node-redshift/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js 9:13-33
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/node-redshift/node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/node-redshift/lib/connection.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/node_modules/node-redshift/index.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/lib/redshift.js
@ /Users/desperateusr/Documents/repo/serverless-app/services/apiService/handler.js
```

My serverless is not using webpack, I've been trying to use "serverless-bundle-no-pg-native" but that didn't change anything.
I've been spending more than 20 hours on this, I'm starting to turn crazy.

Does somebody have any idea? Thanks.